# How to run few npm scripts in one-line shell command?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have three scripts in `package.json`:

1. Watch server TypeScript
2. Nodemon
3. Webpack

```
    "scripts": {
        "watch-server": "tsc --watch --project ./server/tsconfig.json",
        "watch-node": "nodemon --watch ./server/build/ --watch ./server/templates -e js,json,pug",
        "watch-client": "webpack --config ./webpack/webpack.dev.conf.js --watch"
      }
```

Everytime I start my computer and open VS Code I need to open three separate PowerShell terminals and type in those commands one-by-one. Is there any way to launch these three separate terminals with their own commands in one shell command? Maybe via `tasks.json`?

Answer (score 1):

On linux or any bash terminal, you can use && to combine multiple commands, i
You can do as

```
npm run watch-server && npm run watch-node && npm run watch-client
```

A quick google search for powershell suggested using semicolon
so on powershell you can do something like below if using && does not work

```
npm run watch-server;npm run watch-node ; npm run watch-client
```

Also keep in mind, you can additionally add fourth command in your npm scripts in package.json where you can use one of these combined commands which works for you, like

```
start-all: npm run watch-server && npm run watch-node && npm run watch-client
```

and then run

```
npm run start-all
```

Comment: I did `"watch-all": "npm run watch-server && npm run watch-node && npm run watch-client"`. This only runs first command before first `&&`. With semicolon it's not working at al :(

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin this link might help https://superuser.com/questions/612409/how-do-i-run-multiple-commands-on-one-line-in-powershell